# Does anyone know how to install drivers for Canon MG3200 from web?

Tags: printing, software-installation, canon

Any help greatly appreciated, fairly new to both Ubuntu & linux

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download the drivers from the canon website, since Ubuntu does not provide these drivers. at least for me the drivers Ubuntu provided for canon were not doing their job correctly.

What you need to do:
Browse to the canon website and look for support & downloads for your printer
Select Linux as your OS and search for the correct drivers. You will need the debian package of the IJ printer driver and the Scangear driver, which is needed for printing and scanning respectively.

If you downloaded these, you will need to run them via the terminal, which should happen automatically if you double click on it.

If you did that for both drivers, printing will function correctly. If you want to scan something, you will need to type "scangearmp" in the terminal, which causes the scanning software to run.

Furthermore: Some websites of canon don't have the drivers for Linux. You will need to look on other websites of canon (of other countries) to find them.

Feel free to ask for clarification if it was not clear enough!